# Can you remove a folder structure when copying files in gulp?

Tags: gulp

If I use :

```
 gulp.src(['app/client/**/*.html'])
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
```

The folder structure in which my `.html` files were in, is maintained in the `dist` folder, but I would like to remove the folder structure completely and just a flat hierarchy in my `dist` folder.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You could use `gulp-rename` to accomplish this:

```
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.src('app/client/**/*.html')
  .pipe(rename({dirname: ''}))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
```

Comment: I'm surprised this isn't a standard gulp feature - works perfectly though. Thanks!!

Comment: How would you rate *gulp-flatten* versus *gulp-rename*? Also, is there a built-in feature for that in Gulp 4?

Comment: Throwing copper on an almost year old question: gulp-flatten appears to do the exact thing whereas as rename seems made for a different purpose...it just so happens to achieve the desired result. Therefore, in the interest of "right tool for the job"...if you want to *change* the name, go with rename...if you want to *ditch* the folders, go with flatten.

Comment: I go for gulp-rename instead of gulp-flatten - each lib less is a pain less... and gulp-rename is more generic and common.

Answer (score 32):

You can use gulp-flatten
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-flatten

```
    app
    ├── logo
    │   └── logo.styl
    └── sidebar
        └── sidebar.styl
```

```
    var flatten = require('gulp-flatten');
    gulp.src('app/**/*.styl')
      .pipe(flatten())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
```

```
    dist
    ├── logo.styl
    └── sidebar.styl
```

Comment: How would you rate *gulp-flatten* versus *gulp-rename*? Also, is there a built-in feature for that in Gulp 4?

Comment: From todays perspective I'd reccomend _gulp-rename_ over _gulp-flatten_. The reasons are that rename is more generic, by far more widely used, more lightweight and also but not least, the last release it not as long ago as in _gulp-flatten_.