# How to use gulp-usemin package fonts

Tags: javascript, css, gulp

I'm currently using the [`gulp-usemin`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-usemin) pluign, however I'm struggling with one thing: using the images the package provides!

```
  <!-- build:css lib/css/main.min.css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
  <!-- endbuild -->
```

The font-awesome bower package also comes with the fonts:

`bower_components/font-awesome/fonts/**.*`

I currently compile my css with the usemin plugin:

```
gulp.task('usemin', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/index.html')
        .pipe(usemin({
            css: [minifyCss(), 'concat'],
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});
```

Right now this scans my HTML with the above build paths, and successfully minifies it.

However the problem I have, is that now my font-awesome CSS is looking for the fonts in the wrong place, as they're no longer in the same directory.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Where is the .dest() of the gulp stream?

Comment: Edited my question to show the whole task!

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out by finding this question: [Can you remove a folder structure when copying files in gulp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658011/can-you-remove-a-folder-structure-when-copying-files-in-gulp)

My task is now uses `gulp-rename`:

```
gulp.task('copy-bower_fonts', function() {
    return gulp.src(paths.bower_fonts)
        .pipe(rename({
            dirname: '/fonts'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/lib'));
});
```

The fonts from the packages which look for `../fonts/` now points to a correct location.

Comment: I believe that you can get rid of the *rename* pipe and change your   gulp.src to `gulp.src(paths.bower_fonts, {base: paths.bower_fonts})`.