# Gulp copy all files inside a directory , without directory

Tags: javascript, gulp

This is my gulpfile

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const runSequence = require('run-sequence');
const gulpCopy = require('gulp-copy');

//move client side library from client-lib to public folder
gulp.task('move-file',function(){
    console.log("Move-files");
    return gulp
        .src(['./client-lib/*.js'])        
        .pipe(gulpCopy('./public'))        

});

gulp.task('default',function(){   
    runSequence('move-file');
});
```

I need to copy all js files inside client-lib folder and copy to public folder . But this code copy with folder and my public folders look like

> public->client-lib->myjsfiles

But I need

> public->myjsfiles

Comment: You can find good solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658011/can-you-remove-a-folder-structure-when-copying-files-in-gulp

Comment: You can use the [`prefix`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-copy#options) option. Give it a value, such as 99, to remove all the paths.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you remove a folder structure when copying files in gulp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658011/can-you-remove-a-folder-structure-when-copying-files-in-gulp)

Comment: I tried accepted answer but wont work in my case @Dabbas

Answer (score 1):

**You dont need to use any NPM for this ,**

```
remove `const gulpCopy = require('gulp-copy');` ,
```

and gulpCopy this command from task as well .

and simply try

```
gulp.task('move-file',function(){ 
gulp .src('client-lib/*.js') .pipe(rename({dirname: ''})) 
.pipe(gulp.dest('./public')) 
});
```

Comment: What if i need to just copy my packages with 1-3 MiB of code? Gulp reads it and it slows down the task for a long.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library called `gulp-rename` and here's  simple example:

```
    var gulp = require('gulp');
    var rename = require('gulp-rename');

   gulp.task('html', function(){
     return gulp.src('app/client/**/*.html')
         .pipe(rename({dirname: ''}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
    });
```

More answers:
[Can you remove a folder structure when copying files in gulp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658011/can-you-remove-a-folder-structure-when-copying-files-in-gulp)

Answer (score 0):

```
gulp.task('move-file',function(){
    console.log("Move-files");
    return gulp
        .src(['./client-lib/*.js'])        
        .pipe(gulpCopy('./public', { prefix: 1 }))        

})
```

Here's explanation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-copy#options

`gulp-copy` has an `options` object, where you could use `prefix` value. If you set it to 1, it would remove 1 part separated by "/" of your path. In your case 1 is enough. If you want to remove all directories, then use 99.